# Probability of A given A union B

Tags: probability

What is the probability of A given A union B?
We know that p(A) = 0.5 p(B) = 0.3 p(AB) = 0.1

From my understanding of conditional probability i think it should be p(A)/p(A union B) . Is this correct?

Could I solve this problem using the definition of conditional probability p(A|B) = p(AB)/p(B) and then applying the distributive law.

Comment: You have $P(A), P(B), P(A\cap B).$  To find $P(A\cup B),$ I suggest you make a Venn diagram, rather than resort to formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition of conditional probability, and make use of the *absorption law* of set theory (highlighted in red below), as follows:-
$$P(A|A\cup B)=\frac{P(\color{red}{A\cap(A\cup B)})}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(\color{red}{A})}{P(A\cup B)}$$
So, you are essentially correct.

Comment: (+1) to increase the effectiveness of the color, maybe put only $A \cap (A \cup B)$ and $A$ in red, and leave $P$ and the outer parentheses in black.

Comment: @6005 Thanks for both the upvote and the suggestion on the colouring - have edited accordingly.

Comment: But the OP knows this, no? Since this is clearly in the question and they are actually asking for P(A or B).

Comment: @Did My understanding of the question is that the OP wanted to know whether $P(A|A\cup B)$ could have been calculated using the definition of the conditional probability, which requires calculating $P(A\cup B)$.